# Protected Routes in React Router v6, using useState, but always returns false

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, async-await, react-router

Here is what I'm trying to do. I get a JWT from google, store it in sessionStorage for the time being, and send it through my API for server-side verification.

This is Protected Route which I'm using to wrap around my protected elements. Like so

```
 <Route element={<PrivateRouteClient />}>  
                <Route path="/CDashboard" element={<Client_dashboard /> }>
 </Route>




import axios from 'axios';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Navigate}  from 'react-router-dom';
import {Outlet}  from 'react-router-dom';

 function PrivateRouteClient() {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);
  
  axios.post('http://localhost:8080/something/something', {credential: sessionStorage.getItem("token")})
  .then(function (res){
    console.log(Boolean(res.data["UserAuth"]));
    setIsAuth(Boolean(res.data["UserAuth"]));
    console.log("hi");
    return isAuth;
  })
  console.log(isAuth)
  return isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login/Client" />;
}

  
export default PrivateRouteClient
```

And I cant make the route async cause it will return a promise, and that's not a valid React Component and it throws and error.
Can't quite figure out where I'm doing wrong!

Thanks for reading and helping!

Comment: setIsAuth is an async operation, you have to wait for it to be ready in e.g. useEffect

Comment: Hey @MWO, could you expand a bit more? Like, I should use useEffect? But how?

Comment: can you please edit your post with code instead of a picture? it makes it more easy to create an answer

Comment: Done! Added it to my question now! My bad!

Comment: now you removed setIsAuth?

Comment: Oh, my bad, was trying something else out, done now!

Comment: and what is the output of console.log(Boolean(res.data["UserAuth"]));?

Comment: It's true 

It works within the .then() block, the one outside the block remains unaffected.

Comment: Then I think the console log outside the .then block is false because of what I wrote, setIsAuth is async, but I think you have a different problem. <Navigate> may be used only in the context of a <Router> component. Don't you get this error?

Comment: Yeah, it's false outside cause that is the initial value and it's not changing cause yes, async. And nope, it works fine! I wrap my route, and if it is true, it goes ahead to the page/component, if not, it redirects

Comment: I just cant figure out how to get the correct value of isAuth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Drew's answer helped me A LOT, thanks! useEffect is the way to go!

When we run this snippet, the "initial" value of log is "undefined" [this means the type of isAuth is also undefined]. When we run the axios.post, isAuth is set as a string, and not Boolean, so we cant really convert is using the Boolean() method.

```
 function PrivateRouteClient() {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState();
  console.log("initial")
  console.log(isAuth)

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/something',{credential: sessionStorage.getItem("token")}
    ).then(function (res){
        console.log("setting IsAuth")
        console.log(res.data["UserAuth"])
        // console.log(Boolean(res.data["UserAuth"]));
        setIsAuth(res.data["UserAuth"]);
        return isAuth;
      });
  });

  console.log(isAuth);

  if (isAuth === undefined) return null; // or loading indicator, etc...

  return isAuth==="true" ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login/Client" />;
}
```

Attaching the logs here for reference.

[image]

Comment: Is the backend really returning "boolean" values as strings, or is it still JSON stringified and just needs to be parsed?

Comment: JSON stringified, and needs to be parsed.

Comment: And `res.data.UserAuth` is still a string `"true"`|`"false"` after that? If you have control over the response data then I'd push to update that. Good find though. Cheers.

Comment: Right, yep, I'll update that to Boolean and I should be good to go! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

A couple issues, (1) you are issuing the POST request as an unintentional side-effect, and (2) the code is asynchronous whereas the body of a React component is synchronous.

Use a mounting `useEffect` hook to issue the POST request and wait for the request to resolve. Use an intermediate `isAuth` state value to "hold" until the POST request resolves either way if the user is authenticated or not.

```
function PrivateRouteClient() {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(); // initially undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post(
      'http://localhost:8080/something/something',
      { credential: sessionStorage.getItem("token") },
    )
      .then(function (res){
        console.log(Boolean(res.data["UserAuth"]));
        setIsAuth(Boolean(res.data["UserAuth"]));
        return isAuth;
      });
  }, []);

  console.log(isAuth);

  if (isAuth === undefined) return null; // or loading indicator, etc...

  return isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login/Client" />;
}
```

Comment: Hey @Drew Reese, thanks! But this piece of doesn't work for the false condition for some reason. It's just always true in the second run even though the setISAuth set's it negative

Comment: @MayankYadav Can you clarify what you mean "always return true in the second run"? In the meantime, I'll see if I can standup a codesandbox with the above code for some testing.

Comment: Hey Drew, I figured it out! Just framing an answer and posting